Visual Studio 2022 - Refresh the process list before attempting another attach Error
When I start to Console Application on Visual Studio 2022. I refreshed an process How can I solve it?
OS: Windows 10
Version: .NETFramework 4.7.2
"Refresh the process list before attempting another attach"

Start an application

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

I'm having similar issue.
I removed this line *<Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>*
from the .csprog file and this seems to have fixed the problem for that soln.
I have another project that does not have that in the .csproj file so still having the issue with while trying to debug.
Turns out the issue was related to a windows update which when rolled back fixed this issue.

Same issues but on .NET 4.8.  Started after installing Windows 11 24H2.
Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program...
The process has been terminated.
Refresh the process list before attempting another attach.
This worked for me (Probably GUI version of user27735398's answer).

In Solution Properties (right click on solution, select properties).
Select Build
Checked Prefer 32-bit.


Go to debug -> attach to process, and select the process you want, or do the reattach thing below it.
